# Domain Validation Error

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, redirect

I have a domain on which a create a CNAME, "redirecting" subdomain.domain.pt to another domain. My purpose is to create a client portal that was created on salesforce.
My domain has already a certificate, and my Salesforce site too, so I bought a Comodo EV SSL to certify my subdomain.

I redirect http:// to https:// for both domain and subdomain. I've also a CNAME record pointing www.domain.pt to domain.pt

On my ssl panel my domain validation is giving me some erros.
(http) www.subdomain.domain.pt: .well-known/pki-validation/...
 Not Found (404)
(https) www.subdomain.domain.pt: .well-known/pki-validation/...
 Moved Permanently (301)
and the same for without www

I've create a CNAME record pointing www.subdomain.domain.pt to subdomain.domain.pt but I don't think that's the way. I tried to create a redirect but I never got it.

Can you give me some instructions on what are my erros? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You might check your .htaccess and move it out of the way while the domain ownership is validated, or add something like this to your .htaccess to ignore the .well-known directory:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$`